# Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /../Linux/./../src/color.cpp, line 8000

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I am trying to learn openCv with native code and I am taking reference from [here](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo).
I successfully build the project using ndk-build.
Now I want to make change in [scan.cpp](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo/blob/master/ScanDemoExample/scanlibrary/src/main/jni/scan.cpp) file which is responsible for getting point for image, crop it, scan it and set color.
I want to give different argument for line 321 in file which is
**cvtColor(mbgra, dst, CV_BGR2GRAY);**
Can I give any other argument for **CV_BGR2GRAY**.
If yes HOW? If no WHY?

Please guide me and tell me if I am missing anything.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems that your question is on C++. What is the reason for tagging C and java, but not C++?

Comment: @Yunnosch Oops I am so sorry for that I am so much frustrated  right now might be that the reason..
Can you help me for my this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can give any argument you want. Would you get a reasonable output? It depends. CV_BGR2GRAY expects BGR (3 channel) input and will output gray (1 channel).

If you input is 3 channel BGR (and even if it isn't really BGR, opencv won't care) you can use any 3 channel conversions, for example CV_BGR2HSV which would result in 3 channel HSV output.

If your input is 1 channel - than you won't be able to use BGR 2 GRAY obviously.

```
Mat bgraImage = imread("BGRA_IMAGE.png", -1);  // 4 channel input image
Mat grayImage = imread("GRAY_IMAGE.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);  // 1 channel input image
Mat result;

cvtColor(bgraImage, result, CV_BGRA2GRAY);    // CORRECT, input 4 channel, output will be 1 channel
cvtColor(bgraImage, result, CV_BGR2GRAY);    // ALSO CORRECT
cvtColor(grayImage, result, CV_BGR2GRAY);    // INCORRECT & will crash, input is 1 channel, expecting 3 or 4
cvtColor(grayImage, result, CV_GRAY2BGR);    // CORRECT, input is 1 channel, output is 3 channel
```

You can see all possible color conversions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) and read more about them [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html)

Comment: Thank you But I am not getting what you said. I have written 
Mat mbgra(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
 // init our output image
 Mat dst = mbgra.clone();
 cvtColor(mbgra, dst, CV_BGR2GRAY);
And in mat_to_bitmap()
 if(info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME,"ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888", i);
            Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
            if(src.type() == CV_8UC1){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, CV_GRAY2RGBA);
But it gives me error if I write CV_BGR2GRAY

Comment: ** Mat mbgra(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels); **
Means It's input is channel 4?

Comment: If src has only 1 channel than cvtColor(src, tmp, CV_GRAY2RGBA); is correct, because GRAY2RGBA expects 1 channel as input. If you try BGR2GRAY with 1 channel src as input - it would obviously be incorrect, because BGR 2 gray expects 3 channel as input (4 channel input can be accepted as well) .

Comment: How can I know that which color code expects which channel?Can you provide me the link/data for that!

Comment: link and data were already in the answer, please read more carefully. You can know it from the name of parameter. BGRA for example means that input is in BLUE-GREEN-RED-ALPHA format (1 channel per 1 color = 4 total). GRAY means gray (1 channel per 1 color = 1 total), HSV is HUE SATURATION VALUE (1 channel per 1 color = 3 total) etc

Comment: Thank you @Dmitrii
I got very helpful hint from your answer.
There must be a list of color code like CV_BGR2HSV if I am not wrong..
Can you give me hint from where I can see that list..

Comment: okay 
Thanks a ton
I have accepted your answer but I do not have reputation to upvote  :(